# Klotski Puzzle 2

Tags: geometry, sliding-blocks

Another Klotski puzzle! (rules [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/klotski-puzzle-1))

[image]

[Klotski Puzzle 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/klotski-puzzle-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that multiple consecutive moves of the same block are counted as one, here is a solution:

> El, Dd, Ed, Cd, Er, Brr, Au, Zrruu, Ad, Bll, El, Cu, Dl, Cu, Erd, Dur, Zru, Cl, Zur