# Klotski Puzzle 3

Tags: geometry, sliding-blocks

Another Klotski Puzzle, "The Great D-vide":

[image: The Great D-vide]

[Rules Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/klotski-puzzle-1)

[Klotski Puzzle 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/klotski-puzzle-1)

[Klotski Puzzle 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10292/klotski-puzzle-2)

Comment: I highly doubt these puzzles are easy to solve by thought alone without losing sanity. And once you write a program, solving all boards becomes trivial.

Comment: They're probably not easy, but my testsolvers solved them by hand reasonably quickly. The second point is probably valid though, even for my 30-40 move puzzles in store. Anyways thanks for the feedback! I'll keep trying to find a suitable place to post these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fu, Hru, Err, Zr, Ad, Blu, Zuu, Aur, Bdd, Zlu, Bu, Elll, Ddd, Hd, Fd, Grrr, Zurrd, Glll, Zurr

Had to change my code from BFS to Dijkstra for this one.